# Issue with predict() when trying to display SHAP values from XgBoost?

Tags: python, xgboost

I have ran an XgBoost model and I want to display the SHAP values for the predictions. I am running into an error when I create the variables for SHAP. Here is the code for the XgBoost model that I have fit:

```
reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000)
reg.fit(train_X, train_y,
    eval_set=[(train_X, train_y), (test_X, test_y)],
    early_stopping_rounds=50,
   verbose=False)

df_compare = pd.DataFrame(data=test_y, columns = ["actual"])
df_compare['predicted'] = reg.predict(test_X)

# Model Evaluation
sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true=df_compare['actual'],
               y_pred=df_compare['predicted']))

# load JS visualization code to notebook
shap.initjs()

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(reg)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(test_X)

# summarize the effects of all the features
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, test_X)
```

The error is being highlighted on the shap_values variable, and the error code is:

```
TypeError: predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'validate_features'
```

My objective is to show the contribution of individual predictors on the testing set. This can be done via the "shap.summary_plot()" command based on the GitHub repository by slundberg.

From my initial research, it seems to be a common problem with XgBoost and I am wondering if anyone has any solutions to this issue?

Any help would be great!

Edit: Here is an example of test_X in its current schema:

```
array([[6.13181152e-01, 1.65250069e-01, 6.28375079e-01, 1.65250069e-01,
    7.69355058e-01, 1.65250069e-01, 4.00000000e+00, 1.20000000e+01,
    2.01300000e+03],
   [6.25013774e-01, 1.50569938e-01, 6.40500901e-01, 1.50569938e-01,
    7.84201386e-01, 1.50569938e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00,
    2.01400000e+03],
   [6.35163552e-01, 1.33475880e-01, 6.50902178e-01, 1.33475880e-01,
    7.96936256e-01, 1.33475880e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00,
    2.01400000e+03],
   [6.46226644e-01, 1.09757193e-01, 6.62239401e-01, 1.09757193e-01,
    8.10817057e-01, 1.09757193e-01, 1.00000000e+00, 3.00000000e+00,
    2.01400000e+03],
   [6.59526768e-01, 8.31406390e-02, 6.75869086e-01, 8.31406390e-02,
    8.27504651e-01, 8.31406390e-02, 2.00000000e+00, 4.00000000e+00,
    2.01400000e+03],
   [6.75320666e-01, 6.19388504e-02, 6.92054339e-01, 6.19388504e-02,
    8.47321169e-01, 6.19388504e-02, 2.00000000e+00, 5.00000000e+00,
    2.01400000e+03],
   [6.93341542e-01, 5.11984019e-02, 7.10521752e-01, 5.11984019e-02,
    8.69931864e-01, 5.11984019e-02, 2.00000000e+00, 6.00000000e+00,
    2.01400000e+03],
   [7.10885315e-01, 4.83581090e-02, 7.28500240e-01, 4.83581090e-02,
    8.91943941e-01, 4.83581090e-02, 3.00000000e+00, 7.00000000e+00,
    2.01400000e+03],
   [7.24623815e-01, 4.81424976e-02, 7.42579164e-01, 4.81424976e-02,
    9.09181562e-01, 4.81424976e-02, 3.00000000e+00, 8.00000000e+00,
    2.01400000e+03],
   [7.32223979e-01, 4.68193402e-02, 7.50367651e-01, 4.68193402e-02,
    9.18717446e-01, 4.68193402e-02, 3.00000000e+00, 9.00000000e+00,
    2.01400000e+03],
   [7.36887811e-01, 4.51536143e-02, 7.55147047e-01, 4.51536143e-02,
    9.24569131e-01, 4.51536143e-02, 4.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+01,
    2.01400000e+03],
   [7.43107813e-01, 4.53410592e-02, 7.61521174e-01, 4.53410592e-02,
    9.32373334e-01, 4.53410592e-02, 4.00000000e+00, 1.10000000e+01,
    2.01400000e+03],
   [7.53861886e-01, 4.90621338e-02, 7.72541721e-01, 4.90621338e-02,
    9.45866411e-01, 4.90621338e-02, 4.00000000e+00, 1.20000000e+01,
    2.01400000e+03],
   [7.67586715e-01, 5.63629131e-02, 7.86606635e-01, 5.63629131e-02,
    9.63086879e-01, 5.63629131e-02, 1.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00,
    2.01500000e+03],
   [7.80160005e-01, 6.59919566e-02, 7.99491477e-01, 6.59919566e-02,
    9.78862518e-01, 6.59919566e-02, 1.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00,
    2.01500000e+03],
   [7.89674219e-01, 7.78638363e-02, 8.09241442e-01, 7.78638363e-02,
    9.90799950e-01, 7.78638363e-02, 1.00000000e+00, 3.00000000e+00,
    2.01500000e+03],
   [7.95533832e-01, 9.25097947e-02, 8.15246251e-01, 9.25097947e-02,
    9.98151976e-01, 9.25097947e-02, 2.00000000e+00, 4.00000000e+00,
    2.01500000e+03],
   [7.97006720e-01, 1.09847565e-01, 8.16755635e-01, 1.09847565e-01,
    1.00000000e+00, 1.09847565e-01, 2.00000000e+00, 5.00000000e+00,
    2.01500000e+03],
   [7.94528301e-01, 1.28832231e-01, 8.14215803e-01, 1.28832231e-01,
    9.96890340e-01, 1.28832231e-01, 2.00000000e+00, 6.00000000e+00,
    2.01500000e+03]])
```

Comment: Can you add a mock-up of data to make a fully reproducible example? Also, elaborate on what is `X` in `shap.summary_plot` and why is it different from `test_X`. If I add random data, your code snippet runs fine with `xgboost 0.71` and `shap 0.19.2`

Comment: @MykhailoLisoyi Sorry for the late response. The is all numbers in the exact format as the example I posted above. Hope this helps!

Comment: Doe it work with 
```np.random.seed(312);
train_X = np.random.random((10000,10));
train_y = np.random.randn((10000));
test_X = np.random.random((1000,10));
test_y = np.random.randn((1000))```

If not, then check the package versions. It works for me also splitting your example data into 15:4=train:test samples

Comment: Hello that did not work, same error. I have downloaded the most up to date package. Any suggestions?

Comment: what versions did you use? This seems to be an issue, that is new, as on collaboratory i can reproduce it: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1o_XNsdm4YngCs88N53ZcN0XpV8vQFK4p. Can you roll back to the older release of packages (eg those that i mentioned above), potentially it is a shape issue, so i would start with it?

Comment: I am actually using Google Colab for all of this. I ran "!pip install shap" at the beginning on the code. My shap version is: shap-0.28.3. My XgBoost version is: 0.7.post4. I did also run the last two cells of code from your previous answer and or some reason shap didn't show up, but the xgboost was the same as your output.

Comment: Do `!pip install shap==0.19.2` instead, as i've added now on the top to the example that i linked

Comment: Perfect that did the trick thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me:

`!pip install shap==0.19.2`

Comment: Please elaborate how this fixes the issue.